# XCUITest sign in with Apple

Tags: xcode, automated-tests, ios-simulator, xcuitest, sign-in-with-apple

I'm trying to automate a testing flow in my app, that requires signing in with Apple first. I've figured out how open settings and login with a test Apple ID. I've wrapped that up in a function and call that first (with a check to see if it's already logged in).

When I return to my app, and tapping the sign in with Apple button, I can't find anyway to interact with the sign in with Apple modal, e.g. asking me if I want to share my email address or not, tapping "continue with password" and so on.

I've tried setting up an interruption handler, but it doesn't get triggered.

```swift
let test = addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "") { alert in
            
    print("inside alert:\( alert )")
            
    return true
}
```

I've tried checking for springboard alerts, but it's not an alert:

```swift
let springboardApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
springboardApp.alerts.exists
```

I don't know any other tricks, or how to find the bundle ID of this popup. Any advice?

Comment: You do not need to test Sign In With Apple. You know what it does and it doesn't belong to you.  Test *your* code. That would be a unit test, not a UI test (and it is very hard to write, because Apple has deliberately made it difficult).

Comment: @matt i'm not intending to test apples code, apples code is blocking my path. I want to test my path, without building an elaborate solution to create an artificial flow that doesn't mimic what users will go through

Comment: Some things are just not good subjects for UI testing. As I've said, with some effort can you subject your path to a unit test. Over-reliance on UI testing is a capital error.

Comment: @matt this path changes how large aspects of the entire app work. I'm aware of unit tests and how to use them. I have a unique case, and I want to use automated UI tests on it for a number of reasons

Comment: OK, but "I can't find anyway to interact with the sign in with apple modal". Nor will you, because it's out of process. Now what?

Comment: @matt managed to find what I needed. The fact that its running in a different process is irrelevant to UITests, so long as you know the bundleIdentifer of the app thats holding it. Same way you handle springboard alerts, or go to iOS settings. Answered my own question

Comment: Nice, glad you found a working method.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find the bundle identifier needed `com.apple.AuthKitUIService`

This is not a complete solution that handles all paths through the modal. Just a sample to get through the flow when you have previously signed in. Just leaving this here to show how to wrap something like this up in a function

```swift
sleep(4)
let testApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.AuthKitUIService")
        
let continueButton = testApp.buttons["Continue"]
if continueButton.exists {
    continueButton.tap()
}
        
let shareEmailOption = testApp.tables.staticTexts["Share My Email"]
if shareEmailOption.exists {
    shareEmailOption.tap()
}
        
let continueWithPassword = testApp.buttons["Continue with Password"]
if continueWithPassword.exists {
    continueWithPassword.tap()
}
        
testApp.secureTextFields["Password"].tap()

// Type your password

testApp.buttons["Sign In"].tap()

// Wait for something to show up in your app to denote success / failure
let app = XCUIApplication()
.......
```

How I found this bundle identifier for anyone having similar issues:

running `xcrun simctl list devices --json` in terminal lists all simulators. Find the UDID of the one you are using then either:

run `xcrun simctl listapps <UDID>`

or go to `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/<UDID>/data/Containers/Data` and do a search for "com.apple"

**Note:**

The above code requires, at least, having logged into an apple id on the simulator. This can be handled with the below, supplying your own credentials

```
public static func handleLoggingInToAppleIdIfNeeded() {
    let settingsApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preferences")
    settingsApp.launch()
        
    sleep(2)
    if settingsApp.staticTexts[<your user display name>].exists {
        return
    }
        
        
    settingsApp.staticTexts["Sign in to your iPhone"].tap()
    settingsApp.textFields["Email"].tap()
    // Type you email
        
    settingsApp.buttons["Next"].tap()
    sleep(4)
        
    settingsApp.secureTextFields["Required"].tap()
    // Type your password
        
        
    settingsApp.buttons["Next"].tap()
    sleep(4)
        
    settingsApp.buttons["Don't Merge"].tap()
        
    SharedHelpers.shared.waitForButton("Sign Out", exists: true, inApp: settingsApp, delay: 4)
}
```

followed by a call to wake up your own app

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
sleep(2)
```